# string encoding html

Tags: javascript, node.js, encode

I implemented an http server using javascript and Node.js.

for some reason when the user fills in a form, let's say his full name,
on the server side i get what the user filled in but.. i get "+" between all the words instead of " ".

this is the client side:

```
<form id="register" action="/register" method="post">
<input type="text" id="reg_usname" class="input" name="username" required autofocus/>
<form />
```

this is the server side:

```
var username=request.parameters['username'];//request is an http request that is         returned
```

I have no idea why it is that way.

I can just simply replace all the "+" to  " " but it seems that there is a smarter way to fix the problem.

Comment: Have you considering utilizing Express.JS or at least the lower-level connect framework to handle the http parsing? You can be a opinionated as you like on top of connect layet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data you are passing back to the server is being URL Encoded.

Here's a [the RFC spec from the people who wrote it](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt) that explains how & why.

The JavaScript functions you can use to encode/decode can be found on [this Mozilla Developer Network page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI).